# JavaScript array of objects - 0th element undefined but stringify shows objects

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am pulling an object from backbone.js and when I stringify the object I see string literal

```
'[{"Name":"Testname","Address":"Testaddress","id":"444444444444444"}]'
```

However, when I assign the non-serialized object to a variable and try to access the 0th element, I get undefined. I would expect to get object

```
{"Name":"Testname","Address":"Testaddress","id":"444444444444444"}
```

Is JavaScript not treating

```
[{"Name":"Testname","Address":"Testaddress","id":"444444444444444"}]
```

as an indexed array of objects?

Comment: Is your object a `Backbone.Collection` by any chance?

Comment: your right @fecliff it could be a "Array-like" object

Comment: Yes, it is Backbone.Collection. Since it is array-like and not a real array, how would I handle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access elements of Backbone.Collection by index, use the [`Collection#at`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-at) method:

```
var first = collection.at(0);
```

Alternatively, you can use the `Collection#first` method, which is actually part of the [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#first) library, but is proxied to Backbone collections for syntactic sugar:

```
var first = collection.first();
```

The reason you're seeing the array representation in the serialized JSON is that by convention `JSON.stringify` looks for a method called `toJSON` on the object you give to it to stringify, and if one is found, the return value of that method will be used  instead. The implementation of [`Collection#toJSON`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-toJSON) returns a clone of the collection's internal array of models, and thus the JSON output is an array.

Comment: Thank you. Now I would be grateful for a pointer to the concept I clearly missed - namely why I did not have an indexed array. Is the need for a .at() getter compliments of backbone.js handling of collections or something more general?

Comment: @goldfinger, it's because `Backbone.Collection` is not an array, so you can't index it like an array. Internally Backbone stores the collection's models in a array property called `models`, which is indexable, e.g. `collection.models[0]`.  That's exactly what `collection.at` does, too. See: http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-93

Answer (score 0):

Just tried

```
var arr = JSON.parse( '[{"Name":"Testname","Address":"Testaddress","id":"444444444444444"}]' );
```

and

```
console.log( arr[0] ); // => object
```

What you've described should work.